# Numerical solution to an equation that doesn't have an analytic form

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

Suppose I have an equation 
$$
d=\int_A^B \dfrac{dr}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2M}{r}}}\\
=B\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2M}{B}}-A\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2M}{A}}+M\ln\left( B\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2M}{B}} +B-M\right)-M\ln\left( A\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2M}{A}} +A-M\right),
$$
where $B>A>2M>0$.

I want to solve this equation for $B$ analytically. So far, I have tried

```
Solve[0.1==B*Sqrt[1-2/B]-3*Sqrt[1-2/3]+Log[B*Sqrt[1-2/B]+B-1]-Log[3*Sqrt[1-2/3]+3-1],B]
```

where $d=0.1, A=3, M=1$. However, Mathematica won't give a number.

Is there another way to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `FindRoot` instead of `Solve`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindRoot works, but fun function.

```
inner[M_, xAB_] := Sqrt[1 - (2 M/xAB)];
expr[M_, A_, B_] := 
 B*inner[M, B] - A*inner[M, A] + M*Log[B*inner[M, B] + B - M] - 
  M*Log[A*inner[M, A] + A - M]
FindRoot[expr[M, A, B] == 
  d, {{M, 1.}, {A, 3.}, {B, 2, 2, 4}, {d, 0.1}}]

mine = FindRoot[expr[1., 3., B] == 0.1, {B, 2, 2, 4}]
(* Out: {B->3.05828} *)

original=FindRoot[0.1==B*Sqrt[1-2/B]-3*Sqrt[1-2/3]+Log[B*Sqrt[1-2/B]+B-1]-Log[3*Sqrt[1-2/3]+3-1],{B,2,2,4}]
(* Out: {B->3.05828} *)

In[10]:= mine==original
Out[10]= True
```

PS. Tried `Plot[expr[1, 3, B] == 0.1, {B, 0, 10}]` to see graph of B. Whew!